# How to get webcontent that is loaded by JavaScript using cURL?

Tags: javascript, curl

I am trying to grab the score table from a website. The problem is that the site is using javascript that apparently loads on `document.ready`.

For that reason I don't seem to succeed getting the table and all I get is the buttons at the top of that page.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you tried file_get_contents ??

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28506533/3063226

Answer (score 29, accepted):

cURL will only get you the markup of the page. It won't load any additional resources or process the page. You probably want to look at something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. PhantomJS is a headless WebKit browser. It has its own API that lets you "script" behavior. So you can tell PhantomJS to load the page and dump out the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will need to run this as JavaScript and then  save the dump to a PHP variable using the exec command. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't have to, actually. You can run it directly from the command line. But if you are using this to display it on a website, then yes you can use `exec` from PHP.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you could just fetch the JSON data that makes the table:

http://www.opap.gr/web/services/rs/betting/availableBetGames/sport/program/4100/0/sport-1.json?localeId=el_GR

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will mark Vivins answer as the answer to my question but yours was also really good. I wonder how did you find the json call?

Comment: @m33ts4k0z: No problem. I found it by using the "Network" tab of Chrome's Developer Tools (The same is possible in other browsers as well). Since `document.ready` was involved I guessed that the page probably loaded the information externally.

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan 3 years later LOL