# Trigger a external function with a ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to make a function work (trigger) for example canvas2image or could be any function via a jquery ajax call from a mobile. because I don't use a browser I made a cURL page that calls the page with canvas2image.

the page with the function canvas2image  sends an ajax request to a page that creates the image as .png and saved s it on the server

so I created 3 pages 1 with cURL 1 with canvas2image and 1 to create and save the image.

below the ajax function that appeals to the cURL

```
function mediafunction(){

$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.server.com/curl.php',
cache: false,
success: function(response) {
    // do something
},
error: function(xhr, error) {
    try {
        console.debug(xhr); 
        console.debug(error);
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
   }
});
}
```

the cURL code:

```
$url="http://www.server.com/canvastoimage.php?questid=1";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR     1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

the canvas2image page:

```
var targetDiv = $("#widget");
html2canvas(targetDiv, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

$.ajax({
url: 'saveimg.php', 
                  type: "POST",
                  async: false,
                  //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  dataType: "text",
                  data: { "base64data" : canvasData

                   },
                   beforeSend: function () {

  },
  complete: function (response) {

  },
success: function (result) {

result;

                  },
                  error: function (request,error) {
                  //alert(error);
                  }
                  });



 }
 });
```

the save image page:

```
if ( isset($_POST["base64data"]) && !empty($_POST["base64data"]) ) {    

// get the dataURL
$dataURL = $_POST["base64data"];  

// the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
// that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
$parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
$data = $parts[1];  

// Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
$data = base64_decode($data);  

// create a temporary unique file name
$file = 'mediasave/' . uniqid() . '.png';

// write the file to the upload directory
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

// return the temp file name (success)
// or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
echo $output =    $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';
}
```

this only works if I visit the cURL page with a browser. 
I hope you understand my bad explanation, I did not know how to describe it.

Comment: The problem is that cURL can not execute the javascript, just get the contents of the html page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554113/using-curl-on-a-website-with-javascript

Comment: but it is normal. When you call will cURL, it is server side it will not read html/js code as a browser does, it just get the html/js code but will not interpret that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cUrl is a server side command. It will just read the result, that is html/js code in your case but will not execute it.
To solve your problem( you want to grab and save an image) use instead gd libraries.