# Pull info from website

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I'm looking to pull the timer from this site: http://invasiontimer.com/

But it looks like the timer isn't in html, so the normal curl or wget isn't getting it for me.

Is there any way to get this in a bash script and print it to a text file.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't in html"? It is in the source code, indeed.

Comment: When I use the curl command on the site I can't see the timer in the code that's pasted to the text file.

Comment: likewise, if I grep the test file for the days of the week, I don't get any hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the content loaded by javascript. Check out this answer for more details: [How to get webcontent that is loaded by JavaScript using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554113/how-to-get-webcontent-that-is-loaded-by-javascript-using-curl)