# How can I get dynamic values ​of a page in a get request with curl?

Tags: html, ruby, curl, request

I am trying to get the body of an html page. When I make a get request, the body is empty (there are no divs), the content of that body is dynamic (because the page is an audio call). I want to know if there is a way to capture that body and dynamic content.

The body look like this:

```
 <body>

    <div id="react"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to use it in ruby. Is there an api that allows this?

Comment: Hi, interesting, I wonder if [PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554113/how-to-get-webcontent-that-is-loaded-by-javascript-using-curl) would work

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think that is what I need

Comment: But i need implement in ruby. PhantomJS is it for ruby? or just for js?

Comment: You can't do it with a regular HTML-scraping tool. You need an automated browser. If you want one with Ruby I would recommend looking into Selenium.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. If you want to publish your question and I approve